# How to inherit constructors out-of-line?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, inline, constructor-inheritance

Is it possible to inherit constructors out-of-line in C++ so that they don't (say) get codegened in every translation unit? If so, how?

Comment: Interestingly, inherited ctors are _not_ specified in terms of additional functions in the derived class, but in terms of how initialization of an object with an inherited ctor works: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.inhctor.init
Therefore I don't think the Standard gives you any ways to tweak code generation here...

Comment: Unless you just manually implement every constructor you want to act as though inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't possible.